# How does a Git merge commit know which is the "real" parent?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

As I understand it, Git figures out the current state of a repository by tracing back the changes from the current HEAD through its parents to the root.

Merge commits have two parents, like `C6` here:

[image: Merge commit example from git-scm book]

<sup>[[source]](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)</sup>

I understand the advantages, rationale, etc. for having multiple parents like this.

However, I don't understand how you could trace back through the history here. If your head is on the tip of the `master` branch, and you trace back one commit at a time, how does Git know that `C6`'s “real” parent is `C5`? Is it just something like the order they're stored in the commit file?

Or am I misunderstanding something? Is this not what Git does at all?

Comment: They're both real. If master was merged into iss53 your graph would look pretty much the same. The commit has two real parents.

Comment: When you do a merge, the first parent is your current checkout.  Why do you say C6's "real parent" is C5, and what does "trace back through the history" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "real" parent. A merge has multiple parents, could be more than two, and none of them is more real than the other. What you are thinking of is the **first** parent, and that should give you the answer; parents are ordered.

Comment: Git defaults to "first parent", so `C6^` is the first parent of `C6` (usually the commit you had checked out when you performed the merge, I guess `C4` if you ran `git merge iss53`). You can disambiguate by specifying a parent number, so in that case `C6^1` will be `C4` and `C6^2` will be `C5`